# Why is my list of generators not complete? Missing performance_test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not at all familiar with Rails, but Google (although very unlike it) couldn't help me out this time.

I'm running an installation of Rails set up by somebody else.
This is what I get when I run `rails g`:

```
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  assets
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  jbuilder
  mailer
  migration
  model
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  task

Bootstrap:
  bootstrap:install
  bootstrap:layout
  bootstrap:partial
  bootstrap:themed

Coffee:
  coffee:assets

Jquery:
  jquery:install

Js:
  js:assets

TestUnit:
  test_unit:plugin
```

You'll notice a couple of generators missing, amongst which `performance_test`, the one I'm trying to use.

Why is this list not complete? How can I install missing generators? I'm running version 4.0.3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of rails 4 performance tests are no longer part of the default stack. If you want to use performance tests simply follow these instructions.

Add this line to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails-perftest'
```

If you want to benchmark/profile under MRI or REE, add this line as well:

```
gem 'ruby-prof'
```

Now run bundle install and you're ready to go.

[rails-perftest](https://github.com/rails/rails-perftest)

Comment: Glad to help! You should really take a look at the github page for examples on use and general guidance https://github.com/rails/rails-perftest